How to resolve dependencies before internal deletion checks are performed?
In MDriven, there's a partial method PreDelete() where you can implement special clean-up and also prevent deletion. My problem is that the internal delete checks throw an InvalidOperationException "Cannot delete object, the relation Class.Linkrole is not empty" BEFORE PreDelete() gets called.
My intention was to resolve the situation in my PreDelete(), but how can I do that if the internal checks throw before I even get there?
In detail, I have a class Agreement that has a composite multi-link to Lookup. It also has a composite multi-link to Counter. But then there's also an aggregate multi-link from Counter to Lookup. This makes perfect sense from a business perspective, so let's not get into that. Take it as it is, please.
When I delete an Agreement, the internal checks apparently check that all composite-linked objects can be deleted. But at that point, there are still Lookup objects present, which causes Counter deletion to be disallowed.
What I need to do is to force deleteion of the Lookup objects BEFORE deletion of the Counter objects. My intention was to do this in PreDelete(), but as I mentioned, the internal checks throw before I get there.
Wouldn't it make more sense to call PreDelete() before the internal checks? Otherwise how would I be able to perform special clean-up that resolves such issues?

I agree with you on that it would make more sense to call PreDelete() first, at least from your argument here.
Without understanding fully, I want to check with you that you have considered using the setting DeleteAction to Cascade?

The business rule is that Counter should be retained for history/audit purposes as long as it has Lookup objects linked, but if you delete the Agreement, then the history loses its value and all of it can be deleted. So, setting DeleteAction to Cascade doesn't match the business rules.

I should mention that I see benefits of the current sequence too. Perhaps it would make most sense to add a PrePreDelete hook, or whatever it could reasonably be called? Or improve delete logic to detect the best delete order (complicated!). Or add model elements to sort it out at the model level (not sure how...).

Should we implement a work-around, or should we expect some kind of fix at your end within reasonable time (~weeks)?

Can you copy the model section as an image so that I fully understand what you're trying to do? Both for finding a work-around and later for understanding how added a PrePreDelete will help.

Will send it in a support ticket.

Support ticket submitted.
